# Local Notification not triggering after changing device time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have local notification setup in one of my application which remind the user regarding medication on a regular basis and n times daily depends on user selection. If the user setup the reminder in the application and changes the date on device setting, reminder not triggering for the next scheduled time. But works fine for the other scheduled times. First notification scheduled is missing. Works fine for normal scenarios. Anyone faced similar issues? TIA. Code snippet as follows:

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;

[center setNotificationCategories:[NSSet set]];
    
UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound + UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              if (!granted) {
                                  PRLog(@"Something went wrong");
                              }else{
                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                                  });
                                  
                                  [LocalNotificationShared registerCategories];
                              }
                          }];
```

}

and triggering part like:

```
NSDateComponents *triggerDate = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond|NSCalendarUnitTimeZone fromDate:date]; UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:triggerDate repeats:NO];

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])];
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:s
                                                                         content:content trigger:trigger];

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
       if (error != nil) {
           PRLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
       }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've observed, the time interval for a scheduled notification is independent of the device time. So if you schedule a notification for an hour away, and then set your device time to 59 minutes ahead, it won't matter - you will still have to wait the full hour for it to trigger.